# JavaScript list import in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to implement a map in my website using Google v3 API. I'm trying to save the coordinates of a path in the server that the user generates by clicking on the map. I'm doing all this in JavaScript since the API is in JavaScript. For the backend I'm using Django.

When I'm creating the path, everything gets stored in a JavaScript array.

My question is, how do I store that array in a django model?

My research until now has not been successful and most people suggest using geodjango for the project. But I personally found it very complicated so I only expect answers that are regarding the google map API.

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: As of now I'm just looking for a technique to send the JavaScript array generated on the client side to the server, I haven't been successful yet.

Comment: How is it different than any other Javascript array? I would assume that an Ajax POST request would suffice.